# Is any hardware Simulator available under MFI(Made for iPod)

Tags: iphone, ipad, ipod-touch, mfi

I have to develop a application that will communicate with some external device.I would be writing the communication protocol for hardware also .As I know external hardware should be MFI compatible.But can we get some hardware simulator for Mac/Windows through which we can do a communication with  iPod/iPhone/iPad.

I am thinking of acquiring the MFI license for testing the app in actual device, if this goes well .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to join the MFI program first. 
Without MFI you don't have access to the documentation and most important to the authentication chip you will need to communicate with the external hardware.

Comment: Thanks fluchtpunkt for your answer

Comment: I have Mfi registered device where can I find Protocol so that I can enter it into plist of iOS app. I am beginner in Mfi and have read  EADemo of developers site but it doesn't detect anything as I think the reason is protocol entry in plist! Please help.